# Difference between redirect and iframe

Tags: magento2, redirect, iframe

I want to know what is the difference between Magento v2.3.1 (iFrame) and Magento v2.2.3 (Redirect)

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more, so that someone can try to answer?

Comment: i am trying to upgrade paygate extension.
Here there are two packages.
1. DPO PayGate Magento plugin v2.2.9 for Magento v2.3.1 (Redirect)
2. DPO PayGate Magento plugin v2.2.9 for Magento v2.3.1 (iFrame)

I am not getting which one to use

Answer (score 0):

Both plugins work similarly. Only major difference is that after clicking 'place order', the iFrame version opens a popup and loads the Paygate payment form in an iframe within, while the Redirect version will redirect the customer away from the checkout page to a Paygate payment page.

Both versions will redirect to the Magento order success page after successful payment.